# How to render a table like the first picture use CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

[image]

I want to CSS a table, but I can't render the line between "tr":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS:

```
td {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add attribute `rules="all"` to your `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the CSS on the tr element doesn't always work out too well.

You could try something like this if you're going for just row borders:

```
td {
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
table {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
td {
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    width:50px;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/MsYdJ/19/)